# Cannot Connect to PowerCli through VimClient

Tags: c#

I have a project, where I'm trying to connect to PowerCLI through c#, When I'm trying to connect I'm getting error such as

> *Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface
>   'VMware.Vim.VimClient'*

```
VimClient client = new VimClient();
```

Answer (score 6):

It's

```
VimClient client = new VimClientImpl()
```

these days.